# How would I use divide each row by the SUM of another column?

Tags: sql, denodo

The database is as follows:

| ID | Classification | emissions | market_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Type A | 0.04 | 5.67 |
| 2 | Type B | 0.01 | 6.12 |

I am trying to add a column whose formula will be as follows:

```
(emissions * market_value) / SUM(market_value) AS Contribution
```

Doing so will turn the database into this:

| ID | Classification | emissions | market_value | contribution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Type A | 0.04 | 5.67 | 0.192 |
| 2 | Type B | 0.01 | 6.12 | 0.005 |

I've tried writing my scripts as follow but have had no luck:

- **Attempt 1:**

```
SELECT
id,
classification,
emissions,
market_value
(emissions * market_value / (SELECT SUM(market_value) from database)) AS contribution
FROM database
```

However, the platform I am doing SQL on, Denodo, does not allow for subqueries within a select statemen.

I've also tried rewriting my query as follows:

- **Attempt 2:**

```
SELECT
id,
classification,
emissions,
market_value,
(emissions* market_value / SUM(market_value)) AS contribution
FROM database 
GROUP BY id, classification, emissions, market_value
```

But this doesn't seem to work either. The SUM function using this format just returns the same value as the "emissions" column per row for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have no denodo to try it out, but it seems to support Common Table Expression (CTE). https://community.denodo.com/docs/html/browse/6.0/vdp/vql/queries_select_statement/with_clause/with_clause

Try this maybe:

```
WITH sum_table (mval_sum) AS
    (SELECT SUM(market_value) AS mval_sum
       FROM database)
SELECT id
     , classification
     , emissions
     , market_value
     , (emissions * market_value / mval_sum) AS contribution
  FROM database
  JOIN sum_table
```

MySQL 8.0 Playground:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ajfdrdXsgK1z4UnrDgbPCL/0